# MSXML Remove Node Not Behaving As Expected

Tags: xml, excel, vba, msxml

I am trying to delete a node from the following XML - Data below is only representative of the acutal data:

```
<StaffMembers>
    <Staff Name="Test1" Date="Date1"/>
    <Staff Name="Test2" Date="Date2"/>
</StaffMembers>
```

My code is as follows:

```
Sub DeleteRecord(strName as string, strDate as string)

'Load Document

    Set xList = xDoc.SelectNodes("//StaffMembers/")
    for each xNode in xList
             If xNode.Attributes.Length > 0 And xNode.Attributes.getNamedItem("Date").NodeValue = strDate Then
                 xnode.parentnode.removechild xnode
                 exit for
             End if
    next xNode

'Save Document

End Sub
```

Resulting XML - as you can see, it is not complete:

```
<StaffMembers>
    <Staff Name="Test1" Date="Date1"/>
    <Staff Name="Tes
```

The correct node is selected, but it is only partially deleted. If I open the resulting XML in Notepad, some of the text of the node remains. Can anyone explain this?

Edit:

I have tried removing each Attribute individually before removing the Element. This suffers from the same problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies. I've managed to narrow the problem down to having a slow network connection. The corruption does not occur when saving to a local folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's an XPath selector that will select those nodes which are named `Test2` ***or*** `Test3`:

```vb
xDoc.SelectNodes("//Staff[@Name = ""Test2"" || @Name = ""Test3""]")
```

For the test VBScript program below I get the following output after deleting those nodes:

```xml
<StaffMembers>
  <Staff Name="Test1" Date="Date1"/>
  <Staff Name="Test4" Date="Date4"/>
</StaffMembers>
```

**Test Program:**

```vb
Option Explicit

DeleteRecord "Test2", "Test3"

Sub DeleteRecord(name1, name2)
    Dim xDoc : Set xDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
    xDoc.LoadXML GetXml()

    Dim xList : Set xList = xDoc.SelectNodes _
        ("//Staff[@Name = """ & name1 & """ || @Name = """ & name2 & """]")

    Dim xNode
    For Each xNode in xList
        xNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild xNode
    Next

    WScript.Echo xDoc.Xml
End Sub

Function GetXml()
    Dim NL : NL = vbNewLine

    GetXmL = _
        "<StaffMembers>" &NL& _
        "  <Staff Name='Test1' Date='Date1'/>" &NL& _
        "  <Staff Name='Test2' Date='Date2'/>" &NL& _
        "  <Staff Name='Test3' Date='Date3'/>" &NL& _
        "  <Staff Name='Test4' Date='Date4'/>" &NL& _
        "</StaffMembers>"
End Function
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the answer. The above code does work in your Test Program, but doesn't translate to mine. I can confirm the correct node is being selected - I've achieved this by Debug.Print the BaseName and Attributes to be sure. The ParentNode is definitely 'StaffMemebers' and the BaseName and attributes match perfectly. Can you think of any reason why it is deleting strange parts of the XML? I can't think why it would delete the closing tags of the Root, for example

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense. Can you point me in the direction of XPath documentation to selet a node with a specific attribute value?

Comment: Another observation: `DeleteRecord` is not making use of its `strName` argument.

Comment: I've simplified the XML and Sub due to sensitive data. It is being used in the full sub.

Comment: I have revised my test program once again to show the deletion of multiple elements *without* needing to resort to a temporary array. Admittedly, my answer shows what is possible, but does not explain the corruption you are seeing when examining your resulting XML output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath to select nodes with matching attribute criteria. For example :

```
.....
Set xList = xDoc.SelectNodes("//StaffMembers/Staff[@Date='Date2']")
For Each xnode In xList
    xnode.ParentNode.RemoveChild xnode
Next xnode
.....
```

Comment: Thanks. I've now tried setting the value to a list, and tried selecting a single node, but i'm having the same problem. It is selecting the correct node, but it isn't fully deleting it. There seems to be something else at play here.

Comment: Could you try using another XML that contains only portion you posted in question, does the problem remains? Anyway, it's hard to diagnose further without being able to reproduce the problem

Comment: Ye,s I've used the sample XML, and I have the same problem - it's most confusing.

Comment: If you comment out/delete codes that remove the nodes, does the problem remain? I somehow suspect it isn't the logic to remove nodes that was wrong, maybe it's just the way you save modified XML or the way you display the result